# Adding a link to a local markdown file inside JSDoc

Tags: webstorm, documentation, jsdoc

I have this function which is typed with Typescript Jsdocs:

```
/**
 * my function description... 
 * @see {@link ../docs/csrf-issues.md} 
 * @param httpClientRef : AxiosInstance
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
export const httpClientSetCsrfToken = async (httpClientRef) => {...}
```

Now I want other developers that read the JSDoc could click on the link:
`@see {@link ../docs/csrf-issues.md}` and get to it easily.

This works if I use an external http link like this:

[image: http link works]

But it doesn't work for relative links to files inside my repo.

**Is there a way to reference a relative path file as documentation help?**

(Its the same issue on WebStorm and VSCode)